# API to analyze ECG readings

Tags: api, data-analysis, health

I am working on a project where I am taking ECG readings from an AD8232 heart rate monitor. I want to perform analysis on it and know whether the ECG readings are of a healthy person or are there any disorders in it. Is there any readily available API which can take the readings and give back a data analysis report as response which can be embedded in my website?